# Change Width of a container if it has particular element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have n number of containers which has some divs. But I need to change the particular container's width which has .
How to achieve this only using css.? (I can do this using Jquery)

```js
if ($(".container #content").length > 0){  
  $(this).closest('.container').css('width','450px'); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
....
</div>
<div class="container">
....
</div>
<div class="container">
..
  <div id="content">...</div>
..
</div>
<div class="container">
....
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! So it's not possible with CSS3??

Comment: You're trying to make `.container` `450px` wide if it contains `#content`? You could make `.container` `display: inline-block` and then give `#content` `width: 450`. That would do it, though hard to say if it would work for you without more context.

Comment: That's an interesting answer. But In my case that each container is a pop-up modal. I can't give `display:inline-block` , Because it will affect all other pop-up modal (I don't want to change anything on other container classes).

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```js
$("#content").closest('.container').css('width','450px');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
....
</div>
<div class="container">
....
</div>
<div class="container">
..
  <div id="content">...</div>
..
</div>
<div class="container">
....
</div>
```

As `id` is unique and there should maximum be 1 element in html with the said id. However, still you have multiple elements having same id in the hierarchy, then the selector can be updated to `$(".container #content")`

Comment: I don't want to use jQuery. Is it possible to set width for that particular container which has content div using css??

Comment: @KaushikC - In comments there is reference to another question, you can find the answer there.